# Images of Basis Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am looking for someone to explain how the images of basis vectors are calculated. There are a ton of problems like this in my textbook, but there is no explanation on how to do the calculation.

[image]

In this solution, how are $T(1) = 0$, $T(t) = 1$, and $T(t^2)=2t$ calculated?

Please help.

Comment: Hint: $T$ is linear. Treat the polynomial as a vector of coefficients and apply the rule.

Answer (score 2):

The question has given you a linear map $T:\mathbb{P}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_2$ and defined it by $T(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2) = a_1+2a_2t$, so it's already given you exactly what this linear map is. You are then given a basis for $\mathbb{P}_2$ namely $\beta = \{1,t,t^2\}$, and asks you to determine $[T]_\beta$.

Just as an aside, in the general setting where $T:V \rightarrow W$ if $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively, then $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ has columns $[T(v_i)]_\gamma $ where $v_i$ are the basis vectors in $\beta$.

In your case $T$ is a map from $\mathbb{P}_2$ to itself and without a change of basis so that $[T]_\beta$ is what you're interested in. This means that you want to compute $[T(v_i)]_\beta$ where $v_i \in \{1,t,t^2\}$. So you do exactly what the linear map tells you to do, to be completely explicit you can think of the basis elements as
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1 + 0\cdot t + 0\cdot t^2 \\
t &= 0 + 1 \cdot t + 0\cdot t^2 \\
t^2 & = 0 + 0 \cdot t + 1 \cdot t^2
\end{align*}
Then for example, $T(t^2) = T(0+0\cdot t + t^2) = 2\cdot 1 t = 2t$. You could also note, as Sean Robertson mentioned, that $T$ is a linear map so that $T(\alpha v+\beta u)= \alpha T(v) + \beta T(u)$ and calculate as such. Can you determine the images of the other basis vectors?

Comment: The $ B$-matrix of $T$ would then be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ so that $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_0 \\  a_1 \\ a_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_0\\a_2   \\ 0\end{bmatrix} =a_0 + 2 a_2 t$?

Comment: I think $[T(1)]_\beta = [0,0,0], [T(t)]_\beta = [0,1,0], [T(t^2)]_\beta = [0,0,2]$ and so $[T]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$ That way you get that $[T]_\beta[a_0,a_1,a_2] = [0,a_1,2a_2]$.

Comment: In your very last expression of the comment, the result of the matrix multiplication should then be (according to your expressions and with the given basis vectors) $0 \,1 + a_1\, t + 2\,a_2 \, t^2$ since $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are just coefficients, not vectors. But that's not what we want.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake so $[T(1)]_\beta = [0,0,0], [T(t)]_\beta = [1,0,0], [T(t^2)]_\beta = [0,2,0]$ and so $[T]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

The basis vectors are calculated by evaluating the expression presented for the linear map in question. It's exactly like how you would calculate the function $$f(x)=x^2$$ for $x=1, 2, 3$. Namely, by evaluating the expression $x^2$. So, $$f(1)=1\\ f(2)=4\\ f(3)=9$$ In your case, the expression is given a bit differently. They explicitly write out the general form of the input for the function. So, what you can now do is, write out the basis vectors in the general form and then evaluate the expression. So, for example, the basis vector $t^2$ would be written as $$t^2=0(1)+0(x)+1(x^2)$$ And evaluating the expression for the basis vector $t^2$, we get that $$T(0(1)+0(x)+1(x^2))=2x$$  Or if you have realised that this is just the differentiation map, then use your knowledge of differentiation to evaluate the basis vectors.